# How do I natively translate SqlType to underlying SQL type declaration?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

Is there a way in .NET SqlClient to translate SqlType to actual SQL type declaration, like

```
SqlInt32  -> "int"
SqlGuid   -> "uniqueidentifier"
SqlXml    -> "xml"
SqlString -> "nvarchar(??)"
```

without doing it manually?

CLARIFICATION: I am trying to automatically refactor a number of SQL select statements, and I need to know what types do they return. I'm planning to do it by running following code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = sql;
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; ++i)
    {
         var type = reader.GetProviderSpecificFieldType(i);
         ... generate some sql code ...
    }
}
```

So, once I got the type, I'm trying to generate some SQL code and use SqlTye returned in GetProviderSpecificFieldType, and I wanted to see if there's already a function I can use that will take SqlType and give me back the SQL declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I used GetSchemaTable in order to get the details of SQL type:

```
    private string __type(SqlDataReader reader, int i)
    {
        var schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        var row = (from DataRow r in schema.Rows 
                   where (int)r["ColumnOrdinal"] == i 
                   select r).First();

        var type = (string) row["DataTypeName"];
        if (type == "nvarchar" || type == "varchar" || 
            type == "nchar" || type == "char")
        {
            int maxLength = (int) row["ColumnSize"];
            if (maxLength == 2147483647) maxLength = -1;
            type += string.Format("({0})", (maxLength > 0) ? 
                        (object) maxLength : (object) "max");
        }
        return type;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of. Since there is no 1:1 correspondence (for example, an `SqlString` can correspond to the SQL Server types `char`, `nchar`, `text`, `ntext`, `nvarchar` and `varchar`), such a function would have to *guess* what the original type was, since this information is no longer available once you got the `SqlString`.

If you know that an `SqlString` always corresponds to an `nvarchar(255)` in your database, you can write such a function yourself, using [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.aspx) as a starting point.

What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is better solution to your problem...

Answer (score 1):

[this could help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594711/how-to-retrieve-net-type-of-given-storedprocedures-parameter-in-sql/1662560)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a total duplicate but there is the [opposite direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293599/mapping-clr-parameter-data/1302912#1302912).

The problem of it being a Many <-> Many mapping is exactly the same though.

Any fully automatic translation would be, at best overzealous (for example mapping any string to a TEXT column), and at worst wrong in some subtle way.

At the very least it would need to be Version dependent, for example should it use DateTime or DateTime2?